# Detect the location of AppData\LocalLow

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to locate the path for the `AppData\LocalLow` folder.

I have found an example which uses:

```
string folder = "c:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\appdata\LocalLow";
```

which for one is tied to `c:` and to `users` which seems a bit fragile.

I tried to use

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

but this gives me `AppData\Local`, and I need LocalLow due to the security constraints the application is running under. It returned blank for my service user as well (at least when attaching to the process).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't appent a `Low` to the returned string?

Comment: or `Path.Combine(localData, @"..\LocalLow")`

Comment: Of course I could append low or use path combine, but I think @Thomas solution is the best one. Since it's already an OS call, I would rather use that.

Comment: Unless Microsoft has promised to leave 'LocalLow' as the name in non-English versions of Windows, it seems like a good idea to prefer the OS call...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration maps to [`CSIDL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx), but there is no `CSIDL` for the `LocalLow` folder. So you have to use the [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457.aspx) instead, with the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` API:

```
void Main()
{
    Guid localLowId = new Guid("A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16");
    GetKnownFolderPath(localLowId).Dump();
}

string GetKnownFolderPath(Guid knownFolderId)
{
    IntPtr pszPath = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        int hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(knownFolderId, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pszPath);
        if (hr >= 0)
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pszPath);
        throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (pszPath != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pszPath);
    }
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);
```

Comment: How-to know A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16 ?

Comment: What is `Dump` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet the GUID is a `KNOWNFOLDERID` constant (see link). `Dump` is a method from [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to display a value.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the suggestion you found is fragile. I didn't know the method from Thomas, but if you still consider keeping it simple, here's a way to detect the drive letter as well as the path separator character. This will still be windows specific, but all three options below work the same outputting "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\LocalLow", where 'MyUser' is the username on the machine you run this on. There are other special folders [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0), but below are the ones you need.

```
// UserProfile = C:\Users\MyUser
string folderFromUserProfile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "AppData", "LocalLow");
string folderAppendingFromLocalAppData = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)) + "Low";
// GetFullPath expands from relative to absolute, removing the ".."
string folderRelativeFromLocalAppData = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "..", "LocalLow"));
```

This assumes you have

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer is effective yet needlessly complex for some use cases.

A quick solution is:

```
string LocalLowPath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).Replace("Roaming","LocalLow");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What happens if the current user's name is `Roaming`?

Comment: See https://xkcd.com/327/