# Is there an official way to locate the OneDrive directory on Windows and Mac?

Tags: onedrive

I need to locate the OneDrive folder on the user's hard drive for an app I'm working on.

I saw this answer for Windows - [Get OneDrive path in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26771265/1048712) - although it is pretty old.

I'm wondering if there is an officially documented way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 8.1 and up, you can use the Known Folder API described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx.   For older versions of Windows, you could look at the registry, which is what you linked to   It might be helpful although there aren't any guarantees from it.

For Mac, there isn't an officially supported way.