# How to rename a .txt document in c# using a name stacked in a string?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm making a desktop WPF app, whose main role is to create a .txt file with the content and name given by the user in 2 different TextBoxes("textHolder" for the content and "docName" for the name).

Basically, the user writes down a name for the document, some content and after he presses the "Save" button, the app creates a .txt document with those file infos. I managed to code the content and saving part, but I'm stuck tryning to change the name of the document.

I've tried to change the name using the .MoveTo method but I can't figure out how to include the name given by the user in the string. (the following code doesn't work properly)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(
        @"C:\Users\alex_\OneDrive\All\Desktop\Texts\newTextDoc.txt");

    sw.Write(textHolder.Text);
    sw.Close();

    string nameOfTheDoc = docName.Text + ".txt";
    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\alex_\\OneDrive\\All\\Desktop\\Texts";
    string pathAndName = filePath + nameOfTheDoc;

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(
        @"C:\Users\alex_\OneDrive\All\Desktop\Texts\newTextDoc.txt");

    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        fi.MoveTo(pathAndName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `string pathAndName = Path.Combine(filePath, nameOfTheDoc);`

Comment: Instead of just saying, *"the following code doesn't work properly"*, it would be helpful if you described what the code is doing improperly, or if there is an exception, include the exception message.

Comment: In the code above, `if (fi.Exists)` will always be `true`. If you're trying to allow the user to change the name, then you may need to keep track of which name the contents were last saved as in a class field, so you can move it.

Comment: When combining parts of paths, consider using `Path.Combine`.  It nicely takes care of some edge cases.  I don't believe that there's a *SpecialFolder* (in the `Environment.SpecialFolders` enum) for the mapped OneDrive location in the file system (the OneDrive web-ish API does have this).  However, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771265/get-onedrive-path-in-windows might be useful.  Why are you even moving things - why not just write it once?  I'm not following the purpose of your code

Comment: By the "the following code doesn't work properly" I meant to say that it just doesn't change the name of the document, but at the same time it doesn't give me any errors. I already said that I've managed to code the content and creating the .text file part, so the name change was the only thing left I had to figure out. I'll try to be more explicit next time, and the problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already creating a `pathAndName` for your desired outputfile. Why not just write to that filename instead of `newTextDoc.txt` and rename afterwards.

And your `pathAndName` is missing a path-separator `\` between the filePath and the fileName part. But you should probably use [System.IO.Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) to create your filenames anyways. This will take care of separators and insert the correct ones.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string nameOfTheDoc = docName.Text + ".txt";
  string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:", "users", ... ,"Texts", nameOfTheDoc);

  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath);
  sw.Write(textHolder.Text);
  sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: for a hard coded directory path, you may as well just use `@"C:\Users\alex_\OneDrive\All\Desktop\Texts"` as the first argument to `Combine` and `nameOfTheDoc` as the second.

Comment: Or look up a lot of it somewhere under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive`