# Is there an API to get an OneDrive special folder without the REST API?

Tags: windows, winapi, onedrive

I'm doing some research regarding OneDrive. I have a desktop application which should sync its settings via OneDrive. I know that the path can be found via the environment variable `OneDrive`, but I read that on Windows it is better to use APIs for that in general.

Now the relevant part: I want to put my data into the "Apps" folder which is unfortunately localized. I just found out that in the REST API it is called the [special folder `approot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_get_specialfolder?view=odsp-graph-online#special-folder-names). Since I want to use OneDrive transparent (without logging in) I cannot use the REST API for that. Is there an alternative to get the path?

Regarding code samples, I would need it in [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29). Okay, nobody does that, so a C++ [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) example will be fine too.

Comment: Don't forget there may be more than one OneDrive installation on a given PC. This API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.storageprovidersyncrootmanager.getcurrentsyncroots will give you the list of such folders (but not only, the OneDrive ones' Id property starts by "OneDrive!"). As for the "Apps" / approot folder question, I have no idea what you're talking about, can you expand.

Comment: @SimonMourier I linked the documentation for the approot in my question. In the one drive is that *special* folder which is localized. e.g. in en it should be "Apps" in de_DE it is "Anwendungen" and I have no idea how that directly is called in different locales. I hope that there is an API to get the absolute path to that base directory so that I can write my config into the right path.

Comment: For local API I've put a sample here (in C# but it's similar with C++) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77777581/403671 . As for "special"/"approot", I don't think this has any equivalent locally (I don't have any Apps folder locally), and OneDrive itself has no official local/Windows API/lib AFAIK.

Comment: You should explain what is not ok in the answer I've provided vs your question.

Comment: Your answer just provide a way to find the one drive, but I am looking for that special folder without using the REST-API (which require authentication). When I get no other answer feel free to write an answer and you can have the bounty. To be honest I don't expect that I'll get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you need, but you can use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` like:

```
HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_SkyDrive, 0, NULL, &path);
```

Comment: I am aware of this API (and AFIK it is not state of the art, since you can have a personal and work drive). My question is about the sub path of that path returned by the API call. Did you check my [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_get_specialfolder?view=odsp-graph-online#special-folder-names)? There you can see the approot folder which is localized. On my computer the path is not "Apps" (as you can guess I don't use English)