# Constant for AppData\LocalLow in Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, environment

Currently to access `LocalLow` I use this:

```
{%USERPROFILE}\AppData\LocalLow
```

But I would like to know if there's a constant for that in Inno Setup, since both `Roaming` and `Local` have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no constant for `AppData\LocalLow`.

You may use Pascal Scripting to resolve it.

To resolve the "LocalLow", one has to use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath).
See also [Detect the location of AppData\LocalLow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4494290/850848).

The implementation involves few hacks, due to a lack of (wide) `PChar` type in Unicode Inno Setup.

```pascal
const
  MAX_PATH = 260;
  AppDataLocalLowGUID = '{A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16}';

// There's no PChar in Unicode Inno Setup,
// pretend the function returns a pointer to an Integer
function SHGetKnownFolderPath(rfid: TGUID; dwFlags: DWORD; hToken: THandle;
  var ppszPath: Integer): Integer;
  external 'SHGetKnownFolderPath@Shell32.dll stdcall';

// And allow the Integer to be copied to string
function StrCpy(Dest: string; Source: Integer): Integer;
  external 'StrCpyW@Shlwapi.dll stdcall';
  
// And allow the Integer pointer to be released
procedure CoTaskMemFreeAsInteger(pv: Integer);
  external 'CoTaskMemFree@Ole32.dll stdcall';

function GetAppDataLocalLow: string;
var
  Path: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if SHGetKnownFolderPath(StringToGUID(AppDataLocalLowGUID), 0, 0, Path) = 0 then
  begin
    // The path should not be longer than MAX_PATH
    SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);

    StrCpy(Result, Path);

    CoTaskMemFreeAsInteger(Path);

    // Look for NUL character and adjust the length accordingly
    SetLength(Result, Pos(#0, Result) - 1);
  end;
end;
```

---

If you need to use the path in non-`Code` section (outside of the Pascal Script), you can use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```
[Files]
Source: myfile.txt; DestDir: {code:GetAppDataLocalLow}
```

And you need to change the function signature to take a dummy parameter:

```pascal
function GetAppDataLocalLow(Param: string): string;
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, to delete file on uninstall from LocalLow with INNO:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{userappdata}\..\LocalLow\MyFile.txt"
```

Comment: This worked for me, and it is way simpler than the accepted answer... thanks Sauli!