# How do I get the path of "LocalLow" on windows 10?

Tags: .net-core

On C# (dotnet core) I can do the following:

```
string fp = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData, SpecialFolderOption.None);
Console.WriteLine(fp);
```

and I get C:\User\ [username] \AppData\Local.

How do I get LocalLow? Is there some Protected Mode variable to set? I don't need to see my app data, but the data of another application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect the location of AppData\LocalLow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494290/detect-the-location-of-appdata-locallow)

Comment: You can get `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` and use `Path.Combine` to append `LocalLow`, or you can use `GetKnownFolderPath` instead

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it's a bit overkill, if no other solutions is available, I'll probably go for AppData and then combine it with LocalLow by hand, as Ken also suggests.